# Ruby on Rails controller and view for Luhn Algorithm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a problem with using methods from a model on a field from view.
I know I should use it from the controller, but I don't know how to do that.

So far I have created a scaffold for Credit Cards with values : **number:int, type:string, validation: string**

Here is my model with methods

credit_card.rb

```
class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :number, presence:true, length: { maximum: 16}

#Methods for luhn validation

#First checking the type of card
    def self.find_type(credit_card)
        # Making sure that the card number is passed as a string
        credit_card = credit_card.to_s
        # Set of statements to return the appropriate card type
        # Firstly the code checks the cards's length
        # Secondly regexp, returns 0 which signals validation
        return "AMEX"   if credit_card.length == 15 && (credit_card =~ /^(34|37)/) == 0
        return "Discover"   if credit_card.length == 16 && (credit_card =~ /^6011/) == 0
        return "MasterCard" if credit_card.length == 16 && (credit_card =~ /^(5[1-5])/) == 0
        return "VISA"   if [13,16].include?(credit_card.length) && (credit_card =~ /^4/) == 0
        return "Unknown"
    end

#Secondly applying the Luhn algorithm on the number to check is the number valid or not
def self.luhn(cc_number)
    result = 0
    nums = cc_number.to_s.split("")
    nums.each_with_index do |item, index|
      if index.even?
        result += item.to_i * 2 >9 ? item.to_i*2-9 : item.to_i*2
      else
        result +=item.to_i
        end
    end
    if (result % 10) == 0
      return "valid"
    else
      return "invalid"
    end
  end

end
```

Now I want to apply these methods before posting a card
so for example I input a number into a text field
card_number: 1234567890123

I apply my first method, and my second method after. And I return a string 1234567890123[card_number]//type of card// valid/invalid

So far when I am using my methods I get different errors
about the fact that my method is being unrecognized.

### Update 1

Here Is my current controller

```
class CreditCardsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_credit_card, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  attr_accessor :number

  def index
    @credit_cards = CreditCard.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @credit_card = CreditCard.new
  end

  def create
    @credit_card = CreditCard.new(

    respond_to do |format|
      if @credit_card.save
        format.html { redirect_to @credit_card, notice: 'Credit card was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @credit_card }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @credit_card.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @credit_card.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to credit_cards_url, notice: 'Credit card was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_credit_card
      @credit_card = CreditCard.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def credit_card_params
      params.require(:credit_card).permit(:number, :type, :validation)
    end
end
```

At the moment its almost plain as it was after scaffolding. I am trying to make it work by using callbacks but I am doing it as a child in fog.

Comment: Show how you use your methods please.

Comment: From what I gather, you say you're getting an error using the `luhn` method... But you still haven't shown us how/where you're calling it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your luhn method implementation logic looked incorrect ! Just rectified this piece of code : 
You can cross verify this by calling CreditCard.luhn("61789372994")
Please check : http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Luhn_test_of_credit_card_numbers

```
 def self.luhn(cc_number)
    result = 0
    nums = cc_number.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)

    nums.each_with_index do |item, index|
      if index.odd?
        item *= 2 
        result +=  item > 9 ? item.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).inject(:+) : item
      else
        result +=item
      end
    end

   return "valid" if (result % 10) == 0
   return 'invalid'
  end
```

Next to call this you just use following code:

```
Creditcard.luhn("61789372994") #will return "valid"
```

---

Next, in your case probably you are trying to have following functionality: 
 - You want to validate the card number, if it's valid then save the record
 - if it's an Invalid then don't store the card and have a valid error message for that.
In this case you can go for following approach:

```
 #credit_card.rb
Class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base 
 #custom  validations.
 validate :valid_card_number? 
  validate :valid_card_type?

  private
  def valid_card_number?
    cc_number = self.number #see your controller#credit_card_params
    #above luhn method body goes here. 
     if (result % 10) == 0  #result you will get from the luhn method.
      errors.add(:number, 'Sorry, an invalid cardNumber Entered')
     end
  end

  def valid_card_type?
   #like valid_card_number? implement this one as well. 
  end
end
```

Now in controller when we will try to save those creditcard record, above validation will be executed automatically.

```
 #credit_cards_controller.rb
    def create
      @credit_card = CreditCard.new(credit_card_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @credit_card.save
          format.html { redirect_to @credit_card, notice: 'Credit card was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @credit_card }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @credit_card.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
```

Comment: Hello sir.
My Validation bases on this exercise
https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/106274
No reverse needed

Comment: but creditcard number "49927398716"(provided in the wiki link) is a valid one! but on validating using your code , this shows as invalid one!

Comment: I don't mind if you use your code, if that suits your need the best, but for saving the record and redirecting you can have above mentioned approach in your controller!

Comment: Thank you your suggestions helped me the most with solving my issue that I had.
I wasn't using self.number , etc inside my methods
Now I am happy

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not sure where you call your methods, or what you're ultimately trying to do I'm not sure this is right but to me it looks like those methods shouldn't be class methods.

```
class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :set_type
  validates :number, presence:true, length: { maximum: 16}
  validate :check_luhn

  #Methods for luhn validation

  #First checking the type of card
  def set_type
    # Making sure that the card number is passed as a string
    credit_card_number = number.to_s
    # Set of statements to return the appropriate card type
    # Firstly the code checks the cards's length
    # Secondly regexp, returns 0 which signals validation
    self.type = 'Amex' if credit_card.length == 15 && (credit_card =~ /^(34|37)/) == 0
    self.type = 'Discover' if credit_card.length == 16 && (credit_card =~ /^6011/) == 0
    self.type = 'MasterCard' if credit_card.length == 16 && (credit_card =~ /^(5[1-5])/) == 0
    self.type = 'VISA'   if [13,16].include?(credit_card.length) && (credit_card =~ /^4/) == 0
    self.type = 'Unknown'
  end

  #Secondly applying the Luhn algorithm on the number to check is the number valid or not

  def check_luhn
    result = 0
    nums = number.to_s.split("")
    nums.each_with_index do |item, index|
      if index.even?
        result += item.to_i * 2 >9 ? item.to_i*2-9 : item.to_i*2
      else
        result +=item.to_i
        end
    end
    if (result % 10) != 0
      errors.add(:number, 'is not a valid credit card number')
    end
  end    
end
```

So I've set the type before validation based on the credit card number and made the luhn check a validation, adding an error when the check fails.

This then means in your controller you can have a standard rails action:

```
def create
  @credit_card = CreditCard.new(credit_card_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @credit_card.save
      format.html { redirect_to @credit_card, notice: 'Credit card was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @credit_card }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @credit_card.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Then it'll render the new action if it's not valid and you simply need to display the errors to the user.

I'll leave any refactoring/changes of the rest of your code to you.